# Correct approach of passing data back in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c

**VC1.h**

```
#import "VC2.h"

@interface VC1 : UIViewController

@property(nonatomic, strong)NSString *vc1String;

@end
```

**VC1.m**

```
VC2 *vc2Obj = [[VC2 alloc]init];
    vc2Obj.vc2String = @"Hello from VC1";
```

VC1 passed value to VC2.

---

**VC2.h**

```
#import "VC1.h"

@interface VC2 : UIViewController

@property(nonatomic, strong)NSString *vc2String;

@property(nonatomic, weak)VC1 *vc1Obj;

@end
```

Trying to pass data back to VC1, but `@property(nonatomic, weak)VC1 *vc1Obj;` giving error, `unknown type name VC1 did you mean VC2`.

I know about delegates but want to know what is wrong with this approach and why its not recognizing VC1?

Comment: Sometimes Xcode will not recognise it, may be a clean and build will work or use @class VC1 and import the header file in the .m file

Answer (score 4):

As kernix said, in VC2.h, you should use `@class VC1`, rather than `#import "VC1.h"`.

The reason is because the two `#import` statements create circular definitions. In VC1.h, you are saying: "to define `VC1` you need to first define `VC2`." But in VC2.h, you are saying: "to define `VC2` you need to first define `VC1`." The compiler can't define both classes first.

The way out of this is to separate *declaring* a class from *defining* a class. The statement `@class VC1;` says: "Hey, I'm going to define a class called `VC1`; I'm not doing it now, but I promise to do it sometime before everything gets linked and run." Now the compiler knows what you mean when you say `VC1`.

Note that you still need to `#import "VC1.h"` in VC2.m otherwise the compiler won't be able to find the definitions it needs to compile `VC2`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of #import "VC1.h" use @class VC1;

Answer (score 0):

VC1.h

```
#import "VC2.h"

@interface VC1 : UIViewController

@property(nonatomic, strong)NSString *vc1String;

@end
```

VC2.h

```
@class VC1;

@interface VC2 : UIViewController

@property(nonatomic, strong)NSString *vc2String;

@property(nonatomic, weak)VC1 *vc1Obj;

@end
```

In order to access the methods of VC1 in VC2 you need to import the VC1.h in VC2.m file.